# Comparing two Linestring geodataframes

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas

I have two geodataframes `new_df` (difference circled in blue) [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6td5.png
which is a geopandas dataframe that is being imported from a shapefile & `post_df`  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPDi7.png which is a geopandas dataframe that is being queried from my PostGIS database. I would like to use the geometry field to find the difference in the two dataframes which should look like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRnhX.png

Here is a screen shot of what the geometry field looks like for the postgis dataframe:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUgRY.png

Here is a screen shot of the geometry field looks like for the shapefile dataframe:   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKoWD.png

Is there a simple way to do this? Perhaps using .sjoin?

I've also tried using something like .merge like you would do in pandas but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400585/invert-of-spatial-join-within-not-within
It's for a polygon with a LineString but it should be similar